# sign in on instagram from mobile device

Tags: ios, swift, oauth, instagram, swift3

I'm currently trying to sign into instagram from my application. I've been following [this](http://www.amaniphoneblog.com/2015/02/integrate-instagram-in-ios.html#) tutorial. However it's written in objective-c so I rewrote it to swift 3.0 (I hope lol).

However it doesn't seem to work like it's supposed to. It seems like it doesn't get the appropriate url request. Maybe I've done something wrong, maybe the tutorial I've used is outdated. I couldn't seem to find any others tho.

This is how my rewritten code looks.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var loginWebView: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet var loginactivity: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet var loadedlabel: UILabel!

    var consumer: OAConsumer!;
    var requestToken: OAToken!;
    var accessToken: OAToken!;
    var receivedData: Data!
    var isLogin: String!;
    var typeOfAuthentication: String!;

    var client_id:String = "";
    var secret:String = "";
    var callback:String = "";
    var authURL:String = "";
    var scope: String = "";

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        super.viewDidAppear(true);

        client_id = "myid";
        secret =  "mysecret";
        callback = "http://whattodo.com/";
        typeOfAuthentication = "UNSIGNED";
        scope = "likes+comments+relationships"

        var authURL: String = "";

        if(typeOfAuthentication == "UNSIGNED"){
            authURL = String(format: "client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&response_type=token&scope=%@&DEBUG=true",
                             client_id, callback, scope);
        }
        else{
            authURL = String(format: "client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&response_type=code&scope=%@&DEBUG=true", client_id, callback, scope);
        }

        loginWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: authURL)!));
        loginWebView.delegate = self;
    }

    func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool{
        return checkRequestForCallbackURL(request: request);
    }

    func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        loginactivity.startAnimating();
        loadedlabel.isHidden = false;
        loginWebView.layer.removeAllAnimations();
        loginWebView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false;
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
            self.loginWebView.alpha = 0.2;
        })
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        loginactivity.stopAnimating();
        loadedlabel.isHidden = true;
        loginWebView.layer.removeAllAnimations();
        loginWebView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
            self.loginWebView.alpha = 1;
        })
    }

    func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error) {
        self.webViewDidFinishLoad(webView);
    }

    func checkRequestForCallbackURL(request: URLRequest) -> Bool{
        let urlString: String = (request.url?.absoluteString)!
        if(typeOfAuthentication == "UNSIGNED"){
            if(urlString.hasPrefix(callback)){
                let range: Range = urlString.range(of: "access_token=")!;
                let test: String = String(describing: range);
                handleAuth(authToken: String(describing: range));
                return false;
            }
        }
        else{
            if(urlString.hasPrefix(callback)){
                let range: Range = urlString.range(of: "code")!;
                let test: String = String(describing: range);
                makePostRequest(code: String(describing: range))
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    func makePostRequest(code: String){
        let post: String = String(format: "client_id=%@&client_secret=%@&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=%@&code=%@", client_id, secret, callback, code)
        let postDate: Data = post.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii, allowLossyConversion: true)!;
        let postLength: String = "\(UInt(postDate.count))"

        let requestData: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL.init(string: "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token")!);

        requestData.httpMethod = "POST";
        requestData.setValue(postLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length");
        requestData.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type");
        requestData.httpBody = postDate;

        var response: URLResponse? = nil;
        let requestError: NSError? = nil;
        var responseData: Data = try! NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(requestData as URLRequest, returning: &response);
        let dict: NSDictionary = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSDictionary
        handleAuth(authToken: dict["access_token"]! as! String)
    }

    func handleAuth(authToken: String){
        NSLog("Successfully logged in with token: " + authToken);
    }


}
```

I've made sure that `disable implicit OAuth` and `enforce signed requests` are both deselected. I also don't see anything strange showing up in my logs.

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?